# Is there a way to integrate Zapier and Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Tags: api, salesforce, integration, zapier

Does anyone have experience with sending leads from a third-party tool to Salesforce Marketing Cloud via Zapier?

Can Zapier be integrated with Salesforce Marketing Cloud?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At time of writing, Zapier does not integrate with Salesforce Marketing Cloud (though there is a [placeholder page](https://zapier.com/apps/salesforce-marketing-cloud/integrations)).

If this is a feature you'd like to see, I recommend writing into Zapier support. Integration requests are tracked, so that's the best way to have your vote heard.